# How do I retrieve the text of a webpage without sentences being broken by newlines?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to retrieve the text from a webpage - my preferred language is Python - so that sentences are not broken mid-sentence by newlines, like this:

```
and then the community
decided to invest in
public parks for the
benefit of the citizens.
```

I have tried dumping web pages from `lynx` and `w3m`, but it breaks the sentences into lines.

I just tried using Beautiful Soup's `.get_text()` method, which should pull out unbroken strings from elements containing text, such as `<p>` tags, but to my surprise, it still breaks sentences into newlines. Maybe this has something to do with newlines already being there in the HTML, or the text having tags like links embedded, breaking the flow of text. (I tried it on [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) webpage.)

I can open the webpage in a browser, select all and copy and paste into a text file, and this preserves the sentences as single lines, but this is not a programmatic solution.

I will try to show GPT-3 an example of the way I would like it to join broken sentences but not lines of code and see if it can replicate the example, but this is fixing the extraction afterwards, rather than before.

What would be a simple, programmatic way to obtain unbroken sentences from the source HTML?

I would really appreciate anybody who can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
def cleanMe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") # create a new bs4 object from the html data loaded
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # remove all javascript and stylesheet code
        script.extract()
    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()
    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    return text
```

And you can optionally add in another line that removes all `\n` `\r` and `\t` following the same join pattern. For example:

```
text = text.replace("\n", " ")
```

can be added right before the return text line in the function. Adding that line for me causes the text in your example to render as: `and then the community decided to invest in public parks for the benefit of the citizens.` which may also be a use case you want.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll study and use this very soon. Just to be sure, will this keep lines separate that are supposed to be kept separate - like lines of code?

Comment: @PeterElbert The function as is will keep the lines separate that are supposed to be separate. If you add in the extra line I mentioned, it will not, it will remove all breaks completely. The function is self-commented for each line to make it very clear what each thing is doing.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is golden.

Comment: Glad I can help.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could join broken sentences in a text file where it’s already happened and it’s too late? For example, man pages have sentences broken into lines, but I can’t join all the lines in Vim, since headers and code will get joined too. How can I specify to only join sentences and not code or headers?

Comment: @PeterElbert you would have to first have the code and headers wrapped in tags that you can then ignore. If it is already all text, then you are out of luck.

Comment: I tried it and it looks like it works. I'd like to try to understand it a little better. The only thing separating sentences was scripts and style tags? Why do you strip the lines? Because extracting the script tags might leave unwanted whitespace? And why did you break lines into phrases on double whitespace? I guess you realized that single spaces are most likely what holds connected things together? Is there any standard library already containing methods like these? Thanks very much for your help, really appreciate it.